# Divide Retrofit service declaration into multiple interfaces

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am creating an app linking to an API with about 265 methods to it. I would very much like to break apart the declaration of these APIs into multiple files to keep them organized and accessible. However Retrofit explicitly disallows combining interfaces through extension.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Interface definitions must not extend other interfaces.
```

I had been trying to declare it as follows.

```
public interface ApiService extends ProfileService, AccountService {
    // Empty interface, methods divided into other services
}

public interface ProfileService {
    @GET("/api/v1/protected/profile")
    public void getProfile(Callback<Profile> callback);

    ...
}

public interface AccountService {
    @GET("/api/v1/protected/account")
    public void getAccount(Callback<Account> callback);


    ...
}
```

There is a discussion about this issue on a pull request. The library authors have decided that extending interfaces like this is not in the spirit of the library.
https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/676

Jake Wharton (the author) says that "Retrofit favors composition." And in response to "Do you really have a single adapter with a ton of proxies?", "Yes. They are generated from a service declaration in protos. One interface per service."

I've been reading about composition vs inheritance and fail to grasp how to achieve the goal of breaking up the declaration.

How can I divide the interface declaration up? Is there a best practice that I'm missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create separate interfaces.

```
public interface ProfileService {

  /* ... */
}

public interface AccountService {

  /* ... */
}

ProfileService profileService = mRestAdapter.create(ProfileService.class);
AccountService accountService = mRestAdapter.create(AccountService.class);
```

Comment: Best practice that I'm missing then. :)

Is there a recommended way of accessing the different services? At the moment I have a static RestClient object and call 

    App.getRestClient().getProfileService().getProfile(new Callback<LinkedInResponse>() {...} );

I suppose using Dagger is probably the elegant way.

Comment: You can use a simple [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 5):

I am still experimenting on if this is the best way to go about using this but here is what I have so far. It may not be the cleanest approach yet but I am liking it versus one service with 100 api calls. Splits it up a little and makes it easier to read.

This is the main class to access the data. I have seen a lot separate out the two static methods I have into a separate class but i just included it as one.

```
public class RetrofitApi {
   public enum ApiTypes {
        USER_API(UserApi.class);

        private final Class<? extends RetrofitApi> apiClass;
        ApiTypes(Class<? extends RetrofitApi> apiClass){
            this.apiClass = apiClass;
        }
        Class<? extends RetrofitApi> getApiType() {return this.apiClass;}
    }
    public static  <T> T getApi(RetrofitApi.ApiTypes type) {
        try {
            return (T) type.getApiType().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static RestAdapter getRestAdapter() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel.HEADERS)
            .build();
        return restAdapter;
    }
}
```

Each service has its own api. This does mean more classes. I split them into api, service, model. API is the high level that you will use and expose. Service is more or less just a list of calls. And Model is the model (data object).

```
public class UserApi extends RetrofitApi {

    private UserService service;

    public UserApi() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter =
                RetrofitApi.getRestAdapter();
        service = restAdapter.create(UserService.class);
    }

    public void login(String email,
                      String password,
                      Callback<User> callback) {
        service.login(email, password, callback);
    }
}
```

Service is the interface. Its more or less just a list of api calls that get exposed.

```
public interface UserService {

    @GET("/api/users/login")
    void login(@Query("email") String email,
                   @Query("password") String password,
                   Callback<User> callback);
}
```

Then to use it.

```
 UserApi api = RetrofitApi.getApi(RetrofitApi.ApiTypes.USER_API);
 api.login(email,password,callback);
```

And here is the project structure. To me, it seems clean at the moment. I am sure it will end up getting big when I have 20+ of them. But it might be a little cleaner when those 20 have multiple calls. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

**Create 2 interface class.**

- ARetrofitApi
- BRetrofitApi

**Place Your Calls**

```
// ARetrofitApi

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("get_favorite_food/{id}")
Call<JsonObject> getFavoriteFood(@Path("id") String userId,
                          @Field("image") String image,
                          @Field("name") String foodName);

// BRetrofitApi

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("get_favorite_sport/{id}")
Call<JsonObject> getFavoriteSport(@Path("id") String userId,
                          @Field("image") String image,
                          @Field("name") String sportName);
```

**In You Builder**

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.4/myapp/";

private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;

private RetrofitClient() {

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                                     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                     .build();
}

public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public ARetrofitApi aGetApi() {
    return retrofit.create(ARetrofitApi.class);
}

public BRetrofitApi bGetApi() {
    return retrofit.create(BRetrofitApi.class);
}
```

**To Call**

```
// Use RetroFit To Feed To MySQL
Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance()
                                  .aGetApi()
                                  .getFavoriteFood(userId,
                                               image,
                                               foodName);

// Use RetroFit To Feed To MySQL
Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance()
                                  .bGetApi()
                                  .getFavoriteSport(userId,
                                               image,
                                               sportName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it looks like Retrofit does not and will not support multiple interfaces. And I say sadly because that means we have to start figuring out not-so-optimal solutions.

In case it helps someone, here's my current solution (in Kotlin, with Moshi as converter):

```kotlin
class MyApi {
    companion object {
        private val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        private val moshiConverterFactory = MoshiConverterFactory
            .create(Moshi.Builder().build())

        private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://example.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(moshiConverterFactory)
            .addClient(client)
            .build()

        val firstApi: MyFirstApi by lazy {
            retrofit.create(MyFirstApi::class.java)
        }

        val secondApi: MySecondApi by lazy {
            retrofit.create(MySecondApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a companion object to keep a single instance. Also, `by lazy` to make sure `create()` isn't called everytime I call `firstApi` or `secondApi`.