# Best practices of using Retrofit2 (multiple service)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm writing an Android app using Kotlin, integrating Retrofit2.

As far as I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong), the "traditional" way of doing this, would be:

1. Creating an interface, which includes method definitions for all my APIs.
2. Passing it to retrofit using retrofit.create(), which implements it for me, and then I have access to all of them using the functions from step #1

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829493/divide-retrofit-service-declaration-into-multiple-interfaces), my question is: 
Is it a better practice to create a separate interface for each of my requests?

e.g. If I have a "LoginRequest", and implement it as I show below (the "create" essentially calls retrofit.create()), the next time I want to add/remove an API I only need to add/remove 1 file, rather than a few places (the request itself, the service from step #1, and all the places that use the methods from step #2). On the other hand, this would cause my app to "know" retrofit2, and I'm not sure this is a good practice either.

```
interface MyRequest {
    fun execute()
}

class LoginRequest (private val email: String, private val password: String) : MyRequest {
    interface LoginRequestService {
        @POST("login")
        fun emailLogin(
                @Body loginRequestBody: LoginRequestBody):
                retrofit2.Call<GetUserDetailsResponse>
    }

    override fun execute() {
        val requestBody = LoginRequestBody(email, password)
        val call = MyRequestManager.create(LoginRequestService::class.java).emailLogin(requestBody)
        MyRequestManager.executeCall(call)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen this implementation before for Retrofit. What's wrong with following the official guide? https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I guess one nice(?) thing here is that you can avoid one monolithic service definition interface file, and everything can split apart. Rather than make the service as part of execute, though, it should be a static member of the class

Comment: `Is it a better practice to create a separate interface for each of my requests?` No, I've done it before and then spent some time to refactor them back together. It only makes sense to make an interface per baseUrl (or different OkClients for example).

Comment: Also, creating a NEW retrofit implementation PER REQUEST is DEFINITELY NOT a better practice.

Answer (score 2):

it would be much better if you follow the official guide https://square.github.io/retrofit/

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}


Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();



GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);

Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

then you can have one Singleton for the Service for easier, I like also to create interfaces for each call like bellow that will be used in any class that I want.

```
interface IListRepos {
    fun listRepos(user: String, onResponse: (MutableList<Repo>?) -> Unit) {
        ServiceSingleton.client.create(GitHubService::class.java)
                .listRepos(user)
                .enqueue(object : Callback<MutableList<Repo>> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<MutableList<Repo>>,
                                            response: retrofit2.Response<MutableList<Repo>>) {
                        onResponse(response.body())
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<MutableList<Repo>>, t: Throwable) {
                        onResponse(null)
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way im doing it in java 
is having 1 interface for all, with separate requests.

Inside

```
public interface ApiInterface {
}
```

i have set all the urls in 1 place for easy edit later on

```
String Base_Url = "http://url.com/store/web/app_dev.php/api/";
String Base_Url_Channel = "http://url.com/store/web/app_dev.php/api/APP_STORE/";
String Image_URL_Online = "http://url.com/store/web/media/image/";
```

and for `retrofit2` method call class

```
public class DataServiceGenerator {

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {

        String url = ApiInterface.Base_Url;
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(url);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
            httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor()); // for debugging
        }
        builder.client(httpClient.build());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
 }
```

Now to call the API im using below method in interface

```
@Multipart
@Headers("Accept: Application/json")
@POST("oauth/v2/token")
Call<Token_Model> token(
        @Part("client_id") RequestBody id,
        @Part("client_secret") RequestBody secret,
        @Part("grant_type") RequestBody username,
        @Part("username") RequestBody name,
        @Part("password") RequestBody password);
```

And for Method itself :

```
Call<Token_Model> call = service.token(createPartFromString("13123khkjhfsdf"),
                createPartFromString("1asd234k234lkh24"),
                createPartFromString("password"), createPartFromString("api@example.com"), createPartFromString("test"));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Token_Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Token_Model> call, retrofit2.Response<Token_Model> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    token_model = response.body();
                    if (token_model != null) {
                        helper.setToken(token_model.getAccess_token());
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.failed_token), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Token_Model> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.failed_token), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: note that you can copy past my code and convert it to kotlin

Comment: This means that every time you make a call to an API, interface of that call would be passed to retrofit, which would then implement it. Correct?

Comment: you dont have to implement anything else, this is the full working code

Comment: you will be getting your call back inside your retrofit method (onResponse)